# Is there a way of getting a tensorflow cumsum with a stop_gradient at each sum?

Tags: tensorflow

So basically something like

```
w[t+1] = stop_gradient(w[t]) + dw[t]
```

but efficient. I'm assuming that a for loop is not great compared to cumsum.

I can also just restructure the code but there might be a clever way to make this work and it would be easier to read.

UPDATE:

Here is a simple example restructuring the problem to avoid the cumsum:

```
import pandas as pd
from pylab import *
ion()
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def get_loss(w, lr=1.0):
    n = tf.range(w[0].shape[0] - 1, dtype=tf.float32)
    loss = 0
    dw = w[1:] - tf.stop_gradient(w[:-1])
    temp = lr * tf.reduce_sum(dw ** 2, axis=range(1, len(w.shape)))
    loss += tf.reduce_sum(temp) / 2
    return loss

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
w = tf.keras.backend.variable(np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10 * np.pi, 1000)[:, None]))

w_ = [w.numpy()]

for i in range(1000):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = get_loss(w) 
    g = tape.gradient(loss, [w])
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(g, [w]))
    if i % 200 == 0:
        w_.append(w.numpy())

ww = np.hstack(w_)

figure(1)
clf()
plot(ww, alpha=0.5)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @mathtick, please provide a more specific use case for this.

Comment: The use case is if you are are modelling an adapted process (a filter or a learning algo if you will) *as a batch*. So solving the transport equation is one example.

I ended up just doing things like this:  $dw = w_[1:] - tf.stop_gradient(w_[:-1])$ and it is fine.

Comment: Hi @mathtick, it would be a great if you can include a minimum reproducible code with test inputs and outputs that needs optimization.

Comment: @TF_Support added a simple example that is basically the transport (advection) equation on the weights. Beware of stability regimes etc. Example use is your weights/params satisfy some physics/dynamics and then you also have some data loss via an observation model. This is typical in data assimilation in weather for example.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if stop_gradients on a cumsum or this version have any performance advantages. This is a bit weird as I think you have a lower triangular system in time os it might not always make sense to solve this as a batch but you could play tricks with "spatially" dependent learning rate to gain some advantages of parallelization. i.e. learn the earlier params harder at first and let that roll through.

Comment: Hi @mathtick, I think if all you want is performance advantages. You could make use of the Tensorflow decorator '@tf.function' in your loss computation. I have tested it on your code snippet and observed *significant* improvements. Training Time elapsed: ```2.285248279571533``` and Training Time elapsed *with @tf.function* : ```1.5897068977355957``` . The simulation is done in Google Colab.

Comment: @TF_Support thanks yes I do that but left it out in the example for simplicity sake.